# Excel VBA, error 438 when adding a new slide to PPT

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a silde in existing powerpoint presentation for each chart in opened excel file. VBA keeps throwing errors. 
In here pptApp.ActivePresentation.Add I keep getting an error that the Object does not support method
And in here ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy that the object variable is not set.

Is is as hopeless as it appears?

```
Option Explicit

#Const EARLYBINDING = False

Sub CopyAndLinkAllChartsToExistingPPT()

#If EARLYBINDING Then
  Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

#Else

  Dim pptApp As Object
  Dim pptPres As Object
  Dim pptSlide As Object
  Const ppLayoutTitle = 1

#End If

    Dim workS As Worksheet
    Dim chartS As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim workS_Count As Integer
    Dim chartS_Count As Integer
    Dim W As Integer
    Dim C As Integer

  'Declaring PPT objects
  Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
  Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoTrue)
  Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)

  'Declaring Excel objects
  Set workS = ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(1)
  Set chartS = workS.ChartObjects

  'Amount of worksheets and charts for the loops
  workS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.worksheets.Count
  chartS_Count = workS.ChartObjects.Count

    'Nested loop for all the worksheets and charts
For W = 1 To workS_Count
      For C = 1 To chartS_Count

            pptApp.ActivePresentation.Add
            pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count 1, ppLayoutTitle
            pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide
            pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Set pptSlide = pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

            chartS.Select
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

            'Pasting chart in PowerPoint slide with a data link
            pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoTrue
    Next C
Next W

  ' Clearing the objects
  Set pptApp = Nothing
  Set pptPres = Nothing
  Set pptSlide = Nothing
  Set workS = Nothing
  Set chartS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you got it all wrong there when you are adding slides. 
You already created a presentation so you just need to add slides and paste charts right ?
What you are doing in your loop (and wrong) is adding a new presentation for each chart that you need to paste, then a slide to it.

Try to simplify it:

```
For W = 1 To workS_Count
  For C = 1 To chartS_Count


        Set pptSlide = pptPres.slides.add(pptPres.slides.count, ppLayoutTitle)

        chartS(chartS_Count).Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy           

        'Pasting chart in PowerPoint slide with a data link
        pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoTrue
  Next C
Next W
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the solution. It explained a lot. I still get the error that the object does not support method/property in the chartS.ChartArea.Copy line

Comment: Yes-I think that is due to the fact that sChartS is a collection of charts not a single object. As you parse through the charts with chartS_Count you need to identify which chart you need to copy using    chartS(chartS_Count).chartArea.copy

Comment: chartS(chartS_Count).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy